# Where is the mistake in this file.svg scripting (with ecmascript)?

Tags: javascript, svg, ecmascript-5

i'm Learning svg, and now i am reading how to use Scripting in file.svg with ecmascript... i have found a tutorial, but i think that there is a mistake...

but where?

```
<script type="text/ecmascript">
<![CDATA[
   function aggiungiRect(){
      var svgdoc=document.getElementById("elementoRadice");
      var newrect=document.createElement("rect");
      newrect.setAttribute("x",10);
      newrect.setAttribute("y",150);
      newrect.setAttribute("width",250);
      newrect.setAttribute("height",100);
      newrect.setAttribute("style","fill:blue;stroke:black;stroke-width:2");
      svgdoc.appendChild(newrect);
   }
   ]]> 
</script>
<rect x="10" y="10" width="250" height="100" style="stroke:black;fill:red;stroke-width:2"/>
```

Besides i want a suggestion:

I must use ecmascript only when is file.svg, while if it is an html page (with a code in svg) i have to use ecmascript or javascript ??

And the ecmascript is (Javascript + DOM) ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify ecmascript or javascript at all. If you leave out the type attribute altogether it defaults to javascript.

ecmascript is just a synonym for javascript.

Additionally you cannot create SVG elements using createElement. You must use createElementNS instead

```
var newrect=document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
```

Comment: thank you, and can you tell me where is the mistake in the code ?

Comment: What is it supposed to do and what is it doing instead? I see one error, it's hard to see what else might be wrong as I don't know what elementoRadice is.